# How to find out whether a certain condition for a specific ID has ever been met in an R data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

My problem is seemingly simple but I still failed to come up with a working solution. Let's suppose I have a data frame from a sporting event. In this data frame, we find unique person identifiers and one observation for each try, and information on whether they passed that specific try.

```
data <- data.frame(
        PersonID = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6),
        TryNumber = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, NA),  
        Passed = c("Fail", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail", "Fail", "Fail", "Pass", NA)
    )
```

We see that Person 1 tried only once and failed, 2 passed on their first try, 3 failed the first try but passed the second etc. And we have Person 6, who ended up in the data somehow but didn't compete.

My desired result is a data frame like this, which tells me which person ever passed or failed during the event (or who we don't have any further information on):

```
1 | Fail
2 | Pass
3 | Pass
4 | Fail
5 | Pass
6 | NA
```

Kind regards and thank you very much!

edit: The data for fail/pass is now provided in character format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for `max` value for each Person.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(PersonID) %>%
  summarise(result = case_when(max(Passed) == 0 ~ 'Fail', 
                               max(Passed) == 1 ~ 'Pass'))

#  PersonID result
#*    <dbl> <chr> 
#1        1 Fail  
#2        2 Pass  
#3        3 Pass  
#4        4 Fail  
#5        5 Pass  
#6        6 NA
```

---

If the variable exists in character format we can make use of `any`/`all`.

```
data %>%
  group_by(PersonID) %>%
  summarise(result = case_when(any(Passed == 'Pass') ~ 'Pass', 
                               all(Passed == 'Fail') ~ 'Fail'))
```

Comment: That's smart. Thank you very much for the idea! To keep it minimal I made the "fail/pass"-variable numeric in my example, but let's say this information exists in character format.

Comment: We can make use of `any`/`all`. See my updated answer @KlausPeter

Comment: Thank you, but this only returns "NA" for me, sadly.

# A tibble: 6 x 2
  PersonID result
*    <dbl> <chr> 
1        1 NA    
2        2 NA    
3        3 NA    
4        4 NA    
5        5 NA    
6        6 NA

Comment: Ohh..I did not notice that you changed the data. I meant to check the values which are associated with 'Pass' and 'Fail'. I updated the answer which works for the new sample data.

Comment: Yeah, should have noticed, myself :-) I consider my question answered. Thank you very much. Gladly bought you a coffee. Make sure you check if I have any further questions .... ;-)

Comment: Oh, one more question! What if I don't want the result to be in a separate table but appended to the existing data frame? I understand that I could join the output with the original data frame by PersonID but that seems like an extra step.

Comment: You can replace `summarise` with `mutate` to get a new column to the same table and thanks for the coffee. :)